# Showing that complex functions with the same derivative on the unit disc differ by a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I have from class:
      If $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, convex and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is
      holomorphic, then f has a primitive.

My proof is:

The fact that $D(0,1)$ is clearly convex and theorem 1 tells us that both $f$
  and $g$ have primitives. It remains to show these primitives differ by a
  constant. Furthermore, it is clear that $f-g$ is also holomorphic as the sum
  of holomorphic functions is holomorphic with
  $\begin{equation*}
  (f-g)'=f'-g'=0\Rightarrow f-g=c
  \end{equation*}$
  As the rate of change of the difference of $f$ and $g$ is 0, meaning the
  difference is constant.

I am uncomfortable with the last part, is it true in complex analysis that a function being constant is equivalent to having a zero derivative? I am concerned because the proof of this I know for the real case uses the mean value theorem.

Comment: On a connected domain,a holomorphic function with derivative zero is a constant.

Comment: got it. I was planning on using convexity which should be easier than proving what you suggested for connected sets.

Comment: don't be affraid of complex derivatives, holomorphic functions are (locally) analytic, and $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_k z^k$ is not complicated to differentiate

Comment: we have not yet proved that holomorphic functions are locally analytic, would this be difficult to prove on my own?

Comment: you will prove it, I'm just telling you that when you see "holomorphic function" you should think to "polynomial or function which is locally as a polynomial" (for example $e^z$ is not a polynomial, but $e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$ making it not so different from a polynomial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a region (i.e., open and connected), $f :U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function, and $f^\prime(z) = 0$ for all $z \in U$, then $f$ is constant. For if we write $$f = u+iv,$$ where $u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$, respectively, then all the partial derivatives $$u_x,u_y, v_x, v_y$$ vanish in $U$. Thus $f$ will be constant along any segment parallel to each of the coordinate axis. Since $U$ is a region, each pair of points of $U$ can be connected by a polygonal path lying entirely within $U$ which is composed with such segments.